# Error al mostrar informacion en un datagridview en c#

Tags: java, c#, vb, datagridview

Estoy realizando un programa de conversión de audio en c#. Todo me va bien hasta que empiezo la conversión y pongo el estado de la misma en un datagridview.

El problema es que no me muestra el estado de la conversión de un listado de audios hasta que termina de realizarse todas las conversiones.

El codigó del datagridview es:

```
private void bStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.bStart.Enabled = false;
            this.bFin.Enabled = true;
            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in Listas.song)
            {
                PJSong song = (PJSong)de.Value;
                this.lista.Rows.Add(song.RUTAOUT, "En Proceso");
                lista.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                Convers.GetMp3ToMp3(song);
                lista.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = "Finalizado";
                lista.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
                i++;
            }
            this.lista.CurrentCell = null;
        }
```

Y el cidigo de la conversión es:

```
public static void GetMp3ToMp3(PJSong song)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(song.RUTAOUT))
            {
                string InputAudioFilePath = song.RUTAIN;
                string OutputAudioFilePath = song.RUTAOUT.Replace(".mp3", ".wav");

                using (Mp3FileReader rMp3 = new Mp3FileReader(InputAudioFilePath, wf => new AcmMp3FrameDecompressor(wf)))
                {
                    tabla.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                }
                var rWave = new WaveFileReader(OutputAudioFilePath);
                
                using (var writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(song.RUTAOUT, rWave.WaveFormat, Listas.type.BITRATE))
                {
                    rWave.CopyTo(writer);
                }
                rWave.Close();
                File.Delete(OutputAudioFilePath);
            }
        }
```

Lo he intentado con un Timer pero no funciona

Tambien poniendo una ventana iniciando con showDialog y así se pone en el datagridview, pero no se cierra dicha ventana y no continua el codigo.

Si algien pudiera darma ena idea lo agradecería

Un saludo y gracias

PD: en java me pasa exactamente lo mismo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que describes pasa porque estas ejecutando todo en el mismo thread y seguido, por lo que el formulario no va a hacer un `Refresh` hasta que termine el evento que se está ejecutando.

Una solución a tu problema podría ser declarar la función `GetMp3ToMp3` como `Async` para que ejecute todas las funciones asincronamente y de esta manera el evento termine mientras se está ejecutando la función y vaya recargando la grid.

```
public static async void GetMp3ToMp3(PJSong song)
{
    //--------- CODIGO --------
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por tu sugerencia convirtiendo el método en otro hilo de ejecución (async) me ha funcionado, aunque aparte de de poner la clausula async he tenido que implementar más código.

Codigo del datagridview:

```
private void bStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.bStart.Enabled = false;
            this.bFin.Enabled = true;
            foreach (DictionaryEntry de in Listas.song)
            {
                PJSong song = (PJSong)de.Value;
                this.lista.Rows.Add(song.RUTAOUT, "En Proceso");
                lista.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                
                Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    await Convers.GetMp3ToMp3(song);
                }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                
                lista.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = "Finalizado";
                lista.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.DarkGreen;
                i++;
            }
            this.lista.CurrentCell = null;
        }
```

Código método conversor:

```
#pragma warning disable CS1998 // El método asincrónico carece de operadores "await" y se ejecutará de forma sincrónica
        public static async Task GetMp3ToMp3(PJSong song)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(song.RUTAOUT))
            {
                string InputAudioFilePath = song.RUTAIN;
                string OutputAudioFilePath = song.RUTAOUT.Replace(".mp3", ".wav");

                using (Mp3FileReader rMp3 = new Mp3FileReader(InputAudioFilePath, wf => new AcmMp3FrameDecompressor(wf)))
                {
                    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(OutputAudioFilePath, rMp3);
                }
                var rWave = new WaveFileReader(OutputAudioFilePath);
                
                using (var writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(song.RUTAOUT, rWave.WaveFormat, Listas.type.BITRATE))
                {
                    rWave.CopyTo(writer);
                }
                rWave.Close();
                File.Delete(OutputAudioFilePath);
            }
        }
```

El warning es por no usar await

Lo dicho gracias y hasta otra